# Android Drag and Drop capture Screen on completion

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, screenshot

I am doing a Android Application in which the user will be able to drag and drop the buttons on the screen then capture that image from there hand set and send it to me. I got the drag and drop, I got the image upload, now I just need to receive a screen grab of the re-positioning of the buttons from the device without the use of DDMs. here is my MainActivity

```
public class DragSymbols extends Activity {


            // Define the symbols and their initial coordinates in arrays. No limit in principle 
            // to how many. Coordinates are measured from the upper left corner of the screen, 
            // with x increasing to the right and y increasing downward



            float [] X = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, };   // Initial x coord in pixels of upper left corner of symbol
            float [] Y = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, };     // Initial y coord in pixels of upper left corner of symbol

            // The Drawable corresponding to the symbol. R.drawable.file refers to file.png, .jpg, 
            // or .gif stored in res/drawable-hdpi (referenced from code without the extension).


            // 5 Buttons in Total
            int[]symbolIndex = {R.drawable.twit,R.drawable.twit, R.drawable.twit,R.drawable.twit,R.drawable.twit,};

            // Instantiate a SymbolDragger instance (which subclasses View), passing to it in the
            // constructor the context (this) and the above arrays.  Then set the content view to 
            // this instance of SymbolDragger (so the layout is being specified entirely by SymbolDragger, 
            // with no XML layout file).  The resulting view should then place draggable symbols with 
            // content and initial position defined by the above arrays on the screen.

            SymbolDragger view = new SymbolDragger(this, X, Y, symbolIndex);
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            setContentView(view);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From what i could understand you want to take the screenshot of your application once the drag and drop is complete. For this u can go throgh the below links which can redirect you in proper direction

http://coderzheaven.com/2011/10/how-to-take-screenshot-of-your-phone-in-android-through-code/

http://coderzheaven.com/2011/10/how-to-create-screenshot-of-application-and-store-it-in-sdcard/

Hope this helps .

Comment: I knew was out there, I just couldn't remember where I saw it at, thanks a Million Deva

Comment: ok I've tried to implement the take screen shot 4 different ways into the above code, the project is clean and the drag and drop items are displaying but my main layout isn't ... any clue why? or how i can capture the screen shot ... maybe run a background thread??? :0